# Расположение файлов с расширением .cz в Joomla

Tags: joomla, cms

В какой папке на сервере сайта, созданного с помощью *Joomla*, могут храниться файлы с расширением `.cz`?

Мне конкретно нужен `estou-srdce.cz` (правда, я не знаю, это кастомный файл или нет).

Answer (score 1):

в исходниках *joomla* нет ни файла с таким именем, ни вообще файлов с суффиксом `.cz`.

для поиска файлов, имеющих суффикс `.cz` (без учёта регистра) по всему дереву каталогов, начинающемуся в «корне» сайта, в операционной системе *gnu/linux* можно воспользоваться такой, например, командой:

```
$ find /путь/к/корню/сайта -iname \*.cz
```